# How to rewrite URL by removing the last two characters within the htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

How to rewrite a URL by removing the last two characters  within the .htaccess like following?

`/blog/?m=20150218` rewrite to `/blog/?m=201502`

I have tried for following but not working:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule ^(/blog/?m=+[0-9]+)$ /blog/?m=/\d{2}$// [L]
```

Comment: What platform? What do you have so far?

Comment: What version of apache? This is info you should have put in the tags for the question. If you had done so It would probably still be open, or at least pointed you to another question with your answer when it closed.

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriting the query string - it's not available in RewriteRule statements. Here's what you have to do (untested):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^((.+&)?m=.+)..(&.*)?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1 [L]
```

This is for 2.2.